# Multiple API requests from CSV file as parameters

Tags: jmeter, api-testing, postman

Let's say that my domain is api.test.com, path is /v1/products and I have to do 1000 API requests with different products as parameters. Examples:

- GET api.com/v1/products/product1
- GET api.com/v1/products/product2
- GET api.com/v1/products/product3
- GET api.com/v1/products/product4

How to do this in Postman or Jmeter and read products as parameters from CSV file?

Comment: I have small video explaining this https://youtu.be/mghQVEb-56o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Postman, you have to set the file on the Collection Runner.

[image]

With this, you can use the variables in your requests as regular variables.

[image]

For JMeter, refer to this Blazer Meter article:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG

Comment: I tried options but it didn't work, because both Postan and Jmeter see my scenario as 1000 separated API requests, not as parameters.

Comment: Do you want to pass all 1000 values at once in one single request?

Comment: What's confusing me that this api request use different products in path but they aren't treated as parameters, no ?product=chocolate in path of the request. No, 1000 requests separated.

Comment: On Postman, when you write api.com/v1/products/{productID}, being productID the CSV header, are not  the sent requests sent to api.com/v1/products/product1, api.com/v1/products/product2, etc?