# Can i check at a time multiple api in jMeter?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, mobile-automation, api

I have started the JMeter in the mobile Application can I test the Multiple API at a time in Jmeter if yes then how can I check the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple API requests from CSV file as parameters](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/36447/multiple-api-requests-from-csv-file-as-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

With JMeter you can do whatever you want, if you need to hit multiple API endpoints with multiple threads (virtual users) at exactly the same moment you need to consider following configuration:

1. List your endpoints in a CSV file, for example:

   ```
   http://example.com/endpoint1
   http://example.com/endpoint2
   http://example.com/endpoint3
   ```
2. Use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so JMeter could read the endpoints from the CSV file

   [image]
3. Set the number of threads in the Thread Group to be equal to the number of concurrent requests you want to send (in my case 3)

   [image]
4. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) to your test plan and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to the number of threads in the Thread Group:

   [image]
5. Run your test and observe Samplers start times using i.e. [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener

As you can see all 3 requests were executed at exactly the same moment of time:

[image]

Comment: I want to hit the post requests, with same url but with difeernt config!! is it possiblE?